# uib-popover not closing on outside click

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I´m using the Angular UI Bootstrap Popover, but I´m unable to get it to close on outside click. I´m using the outsideClick trigger (popover-trigger="outsideClick") Why is this not working?

```
  <button uib-popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'"  
   popover-placement="right"class="btn btn-default"
   popover-trigger="outsideClick">Click Me</button>
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/IgP9EnpHVLJ4JCS8OhJ1?p=preview)

**EDIT:**
This works with ui-bootstrap 1.x.x (e.g. 1.3.3). Is this not supported in 2.x.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because on ui-bootstrap 2.x.x you have to do :

```
popover-trigger="'outsideClick'">Click Me</button>
```

Or use something like

```
$scope.myTrigger = "outsideClick" then
popover-trigger="myTrigger">Click Me</button>
```

Thanks to @AngularPlayer

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your cdn files. Check working code below-

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>

<body >
  <div  ng-controller="PopoverDemoCtrl">
   <h1>Popover Test</h1>

    <button uib-popover-template="'myPopoverTemplate.html'"  
            popover-placement="right"
            class="btn btn-default" popover-trigger="outsideClick"
            >
      Click Me
      </button>


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">

      <label> Why does this popover not close on outside click? </label>
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this not supported in ui-bootstrap 2.x.x ?

Comment: Not according to the documentation on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

"The outsideClick trigger will cause the popover to toggle on click, and hide when anything else is clicked."