# How to hide the uib-popover when clicking outside

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

My uib-popover is not hiding on outsideClick.

```
<button 
    tooltip-placement="bottom" 
    tooltip="{{'common.addRemoveColumn'| translate}}" 
    class="btn btn-default pull-right" 
    uib-popover 
    popover-trigger="'outsideClick'" 
    popover-placement="bottom" 
    uib-popover-template="'gridColumns.html'" 
    data-original-title="{{'common.customizeColumn'| translate}}">
        <i class="fa fa-columns"></i>
</button>
```

I have followed these stackOverflow questions,

[uib-popover not closing on outside click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138694/uib-popover-not-closing-on-outside-click?rq=1)

[How to hide uib-popover on click outside of the popover in angular JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651571/how-to-hide-uib-popover-on-click-outside-of-the-popover-in-angular-js)

and nothing solved the issue.

My angularJs version is 1.3.13.

My Bootstrap version is 3.2.0.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.myTrigger = "outsideClick"
```

then

```
popover-trigger="myTrigger">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately this solution also not working

Answer (score 2):

```
Pls check in below URL: 

https://codepen.io/minhdynasty/pen/ozvAPJ

It will close th pop up
```

Comment: This solution also not working in my mentioned version